# Can I use javax.mail for background email sending?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

I need to send an email from a background thread and I was wondering if I could use javax mail in an android project, or if they are some alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah buddy , you can use  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/1218762)  code to send mail in background what happens in Android api , user has to click on send button manually but in above link you can send mail in background.